# Best practice to manage string literals

Tags: c++, string, constants

What are best practices to manage strings in one file instead of writing them out multiple times? My idea is to create a simple string_library.h file that has all strings in a map and convenient defines to get the names and IDs. Something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

#define SENSOR1_ID 0
#define SENSOR2_ID 1

#define SENSOR1_NAME string_library[SENSOR1_ID]
#define SENSOR2_NAME string_library[SENSOR2_ID]

std::map<unsigned int, const std::string> string_library{
std::make_pair(SENSOR1_ID, "Sensor1 Name"),
std::make_pair(SENSOR2_ID, "Sensor2 HI Name")
};
```

This way the strings only have to be written out once and can be grabbed easily with the defines or from the map. The map might be useful to be able to iterate over the map but maybe some other construct makes more sense.

Comment: What is the *real* problem you want to solve with a solution like this? Storage space? To help with translations? Something else?

Comment: does GNU gettext do what you're after?

Comment: Rather than use macros, I would define your IDs/names as constant static std::strings inside a known namespace

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude when refractoring strings that should be consistent across all files some tend to get forgotten. A refractor of a string that is used in multiple places should only be done once to rule out oversight.

Comment: @Madden well that's what I wanted to do with this. they are const strings inside a map, the macros are just an idea of conviniently accessing the map and can be omitted. I figured having IDs in maps would be easier than thinking of a name for every single string/piece of text.

Comment: @Madden, would you explain why they should be static?

Comment: @jaaq Why not use actual identifiers instead of strings? Then the compiler will help you if you forget one during refactoring, *and* most IDEs will be able to recognize them and prevent it from even happening.

Comment: Reminder:  Any variable declared in a header file is copied into the source file.  There is potential for multiple global variables.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's one of the reasons I decided to ask this question here. Sure one could simply write one const string for each literal but I wonder if there's something that has been proven to be better for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `constexpr` variable:

```
constexpr auto SENSOR1_NAME = "Sensor1 Name";
```

No need for macros, nor the expensive overhead of dynamic memory.